# is there anyway in jquery to have a class selector but without one id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have this code:

```
   function DisableDropDownsMonth() {
        $(".filterDropdown").val(0);
        $(".filterDropdown").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
```

to disable a bunch of select dropdowns that all have this class.  I have a new requirement to call this on every ".filterDropdown" **EXCEPT if the id = "#firstDropdown"**

is there any syntax for this in jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude it, like this:

```
$(".filterDropdown:not(#firstDropDown)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Or possibly judging by your ID, [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) like this:

```
$(".filterDropdown:gt(0)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

This would disable all except the very first `class="filterDropdown"` in the DOM.

Comment: @ooo - nah, just got going for the day, answering some questions while this schema comparison takes forever :)

Comment: I saw that question with no reply but when I clicked it had two answers and 5 up votes..that is quick +1 from for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

should be something like `$(".filterDropdown:not(#firstDropdown)");`

Comment: Remember that a space is a *descendant* selector. You'll want to remove that for it to be correct.

Comment: must be $(".filterDropdown:not(#firstDropdown)");

Answer (score 0):

you can use following syntax

```
$(".filterDropdown[id!=firstDropdown]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/